# Why is PHP not finding my model class in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, classnotfoundexception

I keep seeing this error -

[image]

This is the offending function -

```
private function getInfo(){
    $this->Features = new UserFeatures_Model($this->ID); //<-- Offending line of Code
    /*Other Stuff - Not Relevant*/
}
```

This is from where it's being called -

```
public function __construct($UserID = NULL){
    parent::__construct( TRUE );
    $this->database = $this->load->database('users', TRUE);
    $this->table = 'users';
    $this->idKey = 'User_ID';
    //Assigned UserID should have precedence.
    if (!is_null($UserID)) { $this->ID = $UserID; }
    //If there exists a UserID within this session, automatically load it.
    elseif ($this->session->UserID){ $this->ID = $this->session->UserID; }
    if (isset($this->ID)){ $this->getInfo(); }
}
```

My first guess as to why this is throwing a fit is because I'm calling the getInfo() method in the constructor... but I'm pretty sure that's not the issue.

Anyway, here is the class definition that it is saying does not exist -

```
class UserFeatures_Model extends MY_Model {
    /*Irrelevant stuff since it's not 'seeing' this class anyway...*/
}
```

And here is the directory structure -

[image]

It's there unless I'm hallucinating (a distinct possibility, I am quite tired...)

Why is(are) CI/PHP not finding this class?

Comment: Is `UserFeatures_Model.php` included in `User_Model.php`?

Comment: I'm going to say no because I'm not sure what you mean by that.

I didn't know that classes needed to be included in models...

Comment: I don't use frameworks, so I don't know how CI works about this. But I asked that based on pure PHP behavior, regardless of the software architecture (MVC, MVE, etc). If you're going to reefer a class, a var, a function, etc, from a file inside another file, the first must be required/included inside the second.

Comment: Okay that makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `$this->load->model('UserFeatures_Model');` inside your `getInfo()` controller before you call that model function.

```
private function getInfo($id){
   $this->load->model('UserFeatures_Model');
    $this->Features = $this->UserFeatures_Model->some_function_inside_model($id); 
}
```

Comment: That kinda answers my comment, tks :)

Comment: Okay that makes sense... but then how do I go about initializing the model? The constructor does require a parameter be passed to it.

Comment: Excellent thanks for your clarification and help - I wrote an init(...) function which is meant to be overridden in the base MY_Model class that handles this feature from now on (pretty much just like you said).